Amplify Cognito : How to hide configuration variables in production environment
I use AWS Cognito to authenticate for a React/NodeJs application, it works well, but now I'm trying to push it into production environment
I usually use backend callbacks to protect my environment variables, but I don't know how to do with the Amplify configuration.
In my App.tsx page :
Amplify.configure({
    Auth: authConfig,
} as any)

My issue is that the values of authConfig are visible in some way.
Essay 1:

put anything in a amplifyconfiguration.json file

{
  "Cognito": {
    "userPoolId": "value1",
    "userPoolClientId": "value2",
    "identityPoolId": "value3",
    "allowGuestAccess": true,
    "signUpVerificationMethod": "code",
    "loginWith": {
      "oauth": {
        "domain": "value4",
        "scopes": ["email", "username", "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"],
        "redirectSignIn": ["value5"],
        "redirectSignOut": ["value6"],
        "responseType": "token"
      }
    }
  }
}


and import it into my App.tsx file.

import authConfig from "./amplifyconfiguration.json";
Amplify.configure({Auth: authConfig,} as any)


-> Issue : value1, value2... are visible into my dist/assets files when I build my project.
Essay 2:

Use a callback to get the values from the backend

this.getValues(...).then{authConfig => {
    Amplify.configure({Auth: authConfig,} as any);
}};

-> Issue : value1, value2... are visible into the response of the callback (Console Chrome/Network by example)
Essay 3:

Configure Amplify directly into the backend and return the "Amplify instance" to the frontend.

-> Issue : don't know how to do it, can't create an instance of Amplify or DefaultAmplify.

It seems that these variables are not so sensitive and can be exposed.
Are the Cognito User pool id and Client Id sensitive?
